# What Mytho's emotion does Princess Tutu's pendant belongs to?

Tags: analysis, princess-tutu

In Princess Tutu, what emotion does Princess Tutu's pendent belong to from Mytho's emotions? It was not clearly indicated but must be hinted. Is there any in/out of universe definite answer for it?